# search:search() doesn't return any snippets but /search:response/@total is bigger then zero

Tags: marklogic

I used this expression to search documents

```
search:search(
    '(content:"value of imports")', 
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <constraint name="content">
            <element-query ns="" name="content" />
        </constraint>
        <additional-query>{cts:collection-query("document-binary")}</additional-query>
    </options>
)
```

And had in result

```
<search:response snippet-format="snippet" total="16" start="1" page-length="10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <search:qtext>(content:"value of imports")</search:qtext>
    <search:metrics>
        <search:query-resolution-time>PT0.319222S</search:query-resolution-time>
        <search:facet-resolution-time>PT0.000124S</search:facet-resolution-time>
        <search:snippet-resolution-time>PT0S</search:snippet-resolution-time>
        <search:total-time>PT0.319721S</search:total-time>
    </search:metrics>
</search:response>
```

The search will works correct if I leave only one word in the search expression

```
content:"value"
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet/sample of your data?

Answer (score 1):

The `total` is an unfiltered estimate of the number of results. However the results are filtered by default. When the results do not match the count, you can try the `unfiltered` option to see if that is the reason. You could also try using `xdmp:query-trace` or the [`return-plan`](https://docs.marklogic.com/search:search#opt-return-plan) option for `search:search` to see what is happening. You can also use `cts:uris` to see the document URIs returned by the unfiltered search.

For more about filtered vs unfiltered search, see the docs at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api and https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/count_estimate and https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered

In this particular case the difference between filtered and unfiltered results might be due to the way the fast-phrase index works. Your phrase `value of imports` will turn into a two word term `value of` and a two word term `of imports`. There may be 16 documents containing both of those terms. But that does not mean any of them match the entire three word phrase. If so the index lookup still matches 16, but filtering finds no matches.

Comment: Thank you! You are right.
Can I do something for counting @total more accurate?

Comment: You could try enabling word-positions in the database settings. That will make your indexes somewhat larger, but should make long phrases more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

An element-query contraint matches a container of other elements:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_96729

If you want to match the textual content of an element, try a value or word query:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_21615
- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/appendixb#id_18408

as in:

```
search:search(
    '(content:"value of imports")', 
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <constraint name="content">
            <value>
                <element ns="" name="content" />
            </value>
        </constraint>
        <additional-query>{cts:collection-query("document-binary")}</additional-query>
    </options>)
```

If the document-binary collection tags binary documents, I would expect
an empty result set because the additional query is and-related
to other queries.

Hoping that helps,

Erik Hennum

Comment: If I replace "element-query" to "value" I have in result empty result set and @total=0.
But cts:uris function with my "element-query" constraint returns the same number of links which I have in @total. I think Mblakele was right in comment below.