# Inconsistency between cts:search and cts:uris in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have the following two docs

```
doc1.xml
<root>
  <parent>
    <child id="1"/>
    <child id="2" level="first"/>
  </parent>
</root>

doc2.xml
<root>
  <parent>
    <child id="2"/>
    <child id="1" level="first"/>
  </parent>
</root>
```

When I run:

```
cts:search(/root,cts:element-query(xs:QName("child"),
                                        cts:and-query((cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("child"),xs:QName("id"),"1"),
                                        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("child"),xs:QName("level"),"first")))))
```

the first document is returned.

But when I run:

```
 cts:uris((),(),cts:element-query(xs:QName("child"),
                                        cts:and-query((cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("child"),xs:QName("id"),"1"),
                                        cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("child"),xs:QName("level"),"first")))))
```

uris of both documents are returned.

Please help me understand this inconsistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtering. When you run `cts:search`, by default it filters out false positive results by inspecting the documents returned from the index resolution step. However, `cts:uris` can only run unfiltered, so it always returns all results from the index resolution step.

I suspect if you include the `cts:search` option to run unfiltered, your results will be the same.

```
cts:search(/root,
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("child"),
    cts:and-query((
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("child"),xs:QName("id"),"1"),
      cts:element-attribute-value-query(xs:QName("child"),xs:QName("level"),"first")))),
  'unfiltered')
```

For more detailed information, see MarkLogic's [Query Performance and Tuning Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25727859/908390 - and understand how the XML you put into the database gets indexed. For this particular query enabling element attribute value positions could help, but it'd be better to arrange the XML so it doesn't depend on parallel attributes. For example change `child[@level="first"]` to `child1`, and the query becomes easy to resolve.

Comment: Thank you.I just could not imagine that cts:uris runs unfiltered.Otherwise it's pretty clear.